# Editing XML with BAT

Tags: xml, windows, batch-file

I'm trying to modify XML file (actually just a single attribute's value, **Version**) through BAT. The following is a short sample of my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<APPS>
    <APP Version="Some.Value">
        <!-- APP icon. -->
        <Icon>C:\Program Files (x86)\Somewhere</Icon>
        <Url>http://www.somewhere.com</Url>
    </APP>
</APPS>
```

The following is a BAT file:

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET anotherVariable=New.Value

(FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%a IN (Sample.xml) DO (
   SET "line=%%a"
   SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
   SET "newLine=!line:    <APP =!"
   IF "!newLine!" neq "!line!" (
      SET "newLine=    <APP Version="%anotherVariable%">"
      ECHO.!newLine!
      ENDLOCAL
   ) ELSE (
       SET "line=!line:*:=!"
       ECHO.!line!
       ENDLOCAL
   )
)) > SampleOut.xml
```

But the following is a SampleOut.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<APPS>
    <APP Version="New.Value">
        <!-- APP icon. -->
\Program Files (x86)\Somewhere</Icon>
//www.somewhere.com</Url>
    </APP>
</APPS>
```

The problem is with these path related XML lines (Icon and Url tags) being corrupted. I hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this:

```
type file.xml | repl "(<APP Version=\q).*(\q>)" "$1New.Value$2" xi >newfile.xml
```

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` (by dbenham) - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

This should preserve the following attributes as discussed in the comments:

```
type file.xml | repl "(<APP Version=\q).*?(\q.*>)" "$1New.Value$2" xi >newfile.xml
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply, this works great.
I only encountered 1 issue and that is that the rest of the attributes that follow after the Version attribute are lost. Nevertheless and easy workaround to me was to put Version as a last attribute, but for future reference how would you preserve the rest of the attributes that come after the Version, for example:
<APP Version="Some.Value" Name="App Name" ... >

Comment: link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

As *ÇağdaşTunca* has pointed out in the comments, the provided link for `repl.bat` is broken.
So, I'm posting here the content of that file:

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* Harmless hybrid line that begins a JScript comment

::************ Documentation ***********
::REPL.BAT version 3.3
:::
:::REPL  Search  Replace  [Options  [SourceVar]]
:::REPL  /?[REGEX|REPLACE]
:::REPL  /V
:::
:::  Performs a global regular expression search and replace operation on
:::  each line of input from stdin and prints the result to stdout.
:::
:::  Each parameter may be optionally enclosed by double quotes. The double
:::  quotes are not considered part of the argument. The quotes are required
:::  if the parameter contains a batch token delimiter like space, tab, comma,
:::  semicolon. The quotes should also be used if the argument contains a
:::  batch special character like &, |, etc. so that the special character
:::  does not need to be escaped with ^.
:::
:::  If called with a single argument of /?, then prints help documentation
:::  to stdout. If a single argument of /?REGEX, then opens up Microsoft's
:::  JScript regular expression documentation within your browser. If a single
:::  argument of /?REPLACE, then opens up Microsoft's JScript REPLACE
:::  documentation within your browser.
:::
:::  If called with a single argument of /V, case insensitive, then prints
:::  the version of REPL.BAT.
:::
:::  Search  - By default, this is a case sensitive JScript (ECMA) regular
:::            expression expressed as a string.
:::
:::            JScript regex syntax documentation is available at
:::            http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae5bf541(v=vs.80).aspx
:::
:::  Replace - By default, this is the string to be used as a replacement for
:::            each found search expression. Full support is provided for
:::            substituion patterns available to the JScript replace method.
:::
:::            For example, $& represents the portion of the source that matched
:::            the entire search pattern, $1 represents the first captured
:::            submatch, $2 the second captured submatch, etc. A $ literal
:::            can be escaped as $$.
:::
:::            An empty replacement string must be represented as "".
:::
:::            Replace substitution pattern syntax is fully documented at
:::            http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/efy6s3e6(v=vs.80).aspx
:::
:::  Options - An optional string of characters used to alter the behavior
:::            of REPL. The option characters are case insensitive, and may
:::            appear in any order.
:::
:::            I - Makes the search case-insensitive.
:::
:::            L - The Search is treated as a string literal instead of a
:::                regular expression. Also, all $ found in Replace are
:::                treated as $ literals.
:::
:::            B - The Search must match the beginning of a line.
:::                Mostly used with literal searches.
:::
:::            E - The Search must match the end of a line.
:::                Mostly used with literal searches.
:::
:::            V - Search and Replace represent the name of environment
:::                variables that contain the respective values. An undefined
:::                variable is treated as an empty string.
:::
:::            A - Only print altered lines. Unaltered lines are discarded.
:::                If both the M and V options are present, then prints the
:::                entire result if there was a change anywhere in the string.
:::                The A option is incompatible with the M option unless the S
:::                option is also present.
:::
:::            M - Multi-line mode. The entire contents of stdin is read and
:::                processed in one pass instead of line by line, thus enabling
:::                search for \n. This also enables preservation of the original
:::                line terminators. If the M option is not present, then every
:::                printed line is termiated with carriage return and line feed.
:::                The M option is incompatible with the A option unless the S
:::                option is also present.
:::
:::            X - Enables extended substitution pattern syntax with support
:::                for the following escape sequences within the Replace string:
:::
:::                \\     -  Backslash
:::                \b     -  Backspace
:::                \f     -  Formfeed
:::                \n     -  Newline
:::                \q     -  Quote
:::                \r     -  Carriage Return
:::                \t     -  Horizontal Tab
:::                \v     -  Vertical Tab
:::                \xnn   -  Extended ASCII byte code expressed as 2 hex digits
:::                \unnnn -  Unicode character expressed as 4 hex digits
:::
:::                Also enables the \q escape sequence for the Search string.
:::                The other escape sequences are already standard for a regular
:::                expression Search string.
:::
:::                Also modifies the behavior of \xnn in the Search string to work
:::                properly with extended ASCII byte codes.
:::
:::                Extended escape sequences are supported even when the L option
:::                is used. Both Search and Replace support all of the extended
:::                escape sequences if both the X and L opions are combined.
:::
:::            S - The source is read from an environment variable instead of
:::                from stdin. The name of the source environment variable is
:::                specified in the next argument after the option string. Without
:::                the M option, ^ anchors the beginning of the string, and $ the
:::                end of the string. With the M option, ^ anchors the beginning
:::                of a line, and $ the end of a line.
:::
::: REPL.BAT was written by Dave Benham, with assistance from DosTips user Aacini
::: to get \xnn to work properly with extended ASCII byte codes. REPL.BAT was
::: originally posted at: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3855
:::

::************ Batch portion ***********
@echo off
if .%2 equ . (
  if "%~1" equ "/?" (
    <"%~f0" cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" "^:::" "" a
    exit /b 0
  ) else if /i "%~1" equ "/?regex" (
    explorer "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae5bf541(v=vs.80).aspx"
    exit /b
  ) else if /i "%~1" equ "/?replace" (
    explorer "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/efy6s3e6(v=vs.80).aspx"
    exit /b
  ) else if /i "%~1" equ "/V" (
    <"%~f0" cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" "^::(REPL\.BAT version)" "$1" a
    exit /b
  ) else (
    call :err "Insufficient arguments"
    exit /b 1
  )
)
echo(%~3|findstr /i "[^SMILEBVXA]" >nul && (
  call :err "Invalid option(s)"
  exit /b 1
)
echo(%~3|findstr /i "M"|findstr /i "A"|findstr /vi "S" >nul && (
  call :err "Incompatible options"
  exit /b 1
)
cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" %*
exit /b 0

:err
>&2 echo ERROR: %~1. Use REPL /? to get help.
exit /b

************* JScript portion **********/
var env=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Environment("Process");
var args=WScript.Arguments;
var search=args.Item(0);
var replace=args.Item(1);
var options="g";
if (args.length>2) options+=args.Item(2).toLowerCase();
var multi=(options.indexOf("m")>=0);
var alterations=(options.indexOf("a")>=0);
if (alterations) options=options.replace(/a/g,"");
var srcVar=(options.indexOf("s")>=0);
if (srcVar) options=options.replace(/s/g,"");
if (options.indexOf("v")>=0) {
  options=options.replace(/v/g,"");
  search=env(search);
  replace=env(replace);
}
if (options.indexOf("x")>=0) {
  options=options.replace(/x/g,"");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\\\/g,"\\B");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\q/g,"\"");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x80/g,"\\u20AC");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x82/g,"\\u201A");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x83/g,"\\u0192");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x84/g,"\\u201E");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x85/g,"\\u2026");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x86/g,"\\u2020");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x87/g,"\\u2021");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x88/g,"\\u02C6");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x89/g,"\\u2030");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x8[aA]/g,"\\u0160");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x8[bB]/g,"\\u2039");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x8[cC]/g,"\\u0152");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x8[eE]/g,"\\u017D");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x91/g,"\\u2018");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x92/g,"\\u2019");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x93/g,"\\u201C");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x94/g,"\\u201D");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x95/g,"\\u2022");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x96/g,"\\u2013");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x97/g,"\\u2014");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x98/g,"\\u02DC");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x99/g,"\\u2122");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x9[aA]/g,"\\u0161");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x9[bB]/g,"\\u203A");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x9[cC]/g,"\\u0153");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x9[dD]/g,"\\u009D");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x9[eE]/g,"\\u017E");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x9[fF]/g,"\\u0178");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\b/g,"\b");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\f/g,"\f");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\n/g,"\n");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\r/g,"\r");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\t/g,"\t");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\v/g,"\v");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x[0-9a-fA-F]{2}|\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}/g,
    function($0,$1,$2){
      return String.fromCharCode(parseInt("0x"+$0.substring(2)));
    }
  );
  replace=replace.replace(/\\B/g,"\\");
  search=search.replace(/\\\\/g,"\\B");
  search=search.replace(/\\q/g,"\"");
  search=search.replace(/\\x80/g,"\\u20AC");
  search=search.replace(/\\x82/g,"\\u201A");
  search=search.replace(/\\x83/g,"\\u0192");
  search=search.replace(/\\x84/g,"\\u201E");
  search=search.replace(/\\x85/g,"\\u2026");
  search=search.replace(/\\x86/g,"\\u2020");
  search=search.replace(/\\x87/g,"\\u2021");
  search=search.replace(/\\x88/g,"\\u02C6");
  search=search.replace(/\\x89/g,"\\u2030");
  search=search.replace(/\\x8[aA]/g,"\\u0160");
  search=search.replace(/\\x8[bB]/g,"\\u2039");
  search=search.replace(/\\x8[cC]/g,"\\u0152");
  search=search.replace(/\\x8[eE]/g,"\\u017D");
  search=search.replace(/\\x91/g,"\\u2018");
  search=search.replace(/\\x92/g,"\\u2019");
  search=search.replace(/\\x93/g,"\\u201C");
  search=search.replace(/\\x94/g,"\\u201D");
  search=search.replace(/\\x95/g,"\\u2022");
  search=search.replace(/\\x96/g,"\\u2013");
  search=search.replace(/\\x97/g,"\\u2014");
  search=search.replace(/\\x98/g,"\\u02DC");
  search=search.replace(/\\x99/g,"\\u2122");
  search=search.replace(/\\x9[aA]/g,"\\u0161");
  search=search.replace(/\\x9[bB]/g,"\\u203A");
  search=search.replace(/\\x9[cC]/g,"\\u0153");
  search=search.replace(/\\x9[dD]/g,"\\u009D");
  search=search.replace(/\\x9[eE]/g,"\\u017E");
  search=search.replace(/\\x9[fF]/g,"\\u0178");
  if (options.indexOf("l")>=0) {
    search=search.replace(/\\b/g,"\b");
    search=search.replace(/\\f/g,"\f");
    search=search.replace(/\\n/g,"\n");
    search=search.replace(/\\r/g,"\r");
    search=search.replace(/\\t/g,"\t");
    search=search.replace(/\\v/g,"\v");
    search=search.replace(/\\x[0-9a-fA-F]{2}|\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}/g,
      function($0,$1,$2){
        return String.fromCharCode(parseInt("0x"+$0.substring(2)));
      }
    );
    search=search.replace(/\\B/g,"\\");
  } else search=search.replace(/\\B/g,"\\\\");
}
if (options.indexOf("l")>=0) {
  options=options.replace(/l/g,"");
  search=search.replace(/([.^$*+?()[{\\|])/g,"\\$1");
  replace=replace.replace(/\$/g,"$$$$");
}
if (options.indexOf("b")>=0) {
  options=options.replace(/b/g,"");
  search="^"+search
}
if (options.indexOf("e")>=0) {
  options=options.replace(/e/g,"");
  search=search+"$"
}
var search=new RegExp(search,options);
var str1, str2;

if (srcVar) {
  str1=env(args.Item(3));
  str2=str1.replace(search,replace);
  if (!alterations || str1!=str2) if (multi) {
    WScript.Stdout.Write(str2);
  } else {
    WScript.Stdout.WriteLine(str2);
  }
} else {
  while (!WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream) {
    if (multi) {
      WScript.Stdout.Write(WScript.StdIn.ReadAll().replace(search,replace));
    } else {
      str1=WScript.StdIn.ReadLine();
      str2=str1.replace(search,replace);
      if (!alterations || str1!=str2) WScript.Stdout.WriteLine(str2);
    }
  }
}
```